# Count date in report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, report

My `Medicine` table is in my SQL Server with a column `EXPIRED_DATE`. How can I display the data in Crystal Reports based on the expiration date, where the expired date must be less than or equal to the current date?

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter the *Section Expert*.
2. Choose the Section that contains your data.
3. Click the `x-2` button near the Suppress checkbox.
4. Add this formula: `{@ExpiryDate} < CurrentDate`
5. Save and close

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Record --> Selection formulas --> Report` and write below code.

```
{Databasetable.ExpiryDate} < CurrentDate
```